# Regular Expression in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex

I need to verify input which is like en-US or en-us or ar-AE
I have searched net and found it bit difficult to understand and create one regular expressing on string which is no more than 5 characters in length and should be case in-sensitive.

I created one `[a-z][a-z][-][a-z][a-z]` this one works fine but it doesn't check the length
it will match en-USXYZ also

Regards

Comment: If you are matching cultures, be aware that not all are two two-letter parts. There are some that has. For instance, some chinese cultures deviate from this (such as `zh-Hans`- *Chinese (Simplified)*). Also, some cultures has three parts, such as `sr-Cyrl-BA` - *Serbian, Cyrillic alphabet (Bosnia and Herzegovina)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `^` and `$` to specify the start and end of the string.

```
^[a-z][a-z]-[a-z][a-z]$
```

Or using multiplier:

```
^[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}$
```

You would also have to include the `A-Z` interval for upper case characters, unless you have specified case insensetivity for the Regex object:

```
^[A-Za-z]{2}-[A-Za-z]{2}$
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what anchors are for:

```
(?i)^[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}$
```

The case-insensitive option `(?i)` can also be set when compiling the regex:

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex("^[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use such one:

```
^[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}$
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
^[a-z][a-z][-][a-z][a-z]$
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this regular expression:

```
^[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}$
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use anchors in your expression:

```
^[a-z][a-z][-][a-z][a-z]$
```

Answer (score 0):

`\w{2}[-]\w{2}` should do the trick:

`\w` -> character
`{2}` -> exact 2 times

EDIT: `\w` also allows number so `[a-z]{2}[-][a-zA-Z]{2}`

Comment: It also matches en-USassd while it should fail for such condition it doesnt check for length of string